# How does Series convert from object to number?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, series

I have a pandas.series which consist zip_codes like as: '23123213', '212212', '54545' and some zip_codes looks like: '4344-4343', '7676432-878'. I create def for changing each elements of series to numeric format:

```
def numbers_zip_code(a): # function for changing type of zip_code from object to number
try:
    a = int(a)
except ValueError:
    splitted_a = a.split('-')
    a = int(splitted_a[0]) + int(splitted_a[1])
return a
```

I used this function:

```
X.zip_code = X.zip_code.map(lambda x: numbers_zip_code(x))
```

After that I could use for this series method describe():

```
X.zip_code.describe()
```

Results:

- count     159880
- unique      3498
- top        48227
- freq        7316
- Name: zip_code, dtype: int64

Also I checked each element in series using circle for:

```
object_list = [] #create lists with columns type object and another with numbers
number_list = []
for i in X.zip_code:
    if i == 'object':
        object_list.append(i)
    else:
        number_list.append(i)
len(object_list)
```

Result:
0

And it's fine... but when I check whole dataframe (series with zip_codes is a part of df) and for this column (zip_code) type again is 'object' !!!! Really, I don't understand I should do...

```
X.dtypes
```

Results:

- ticket_id                       int64
- agency_name                    object
- inspector_name                 object
- violator_name                  object
- violation_street_number       float64
- violation_street_name          object
- mailing_address_str_number    float64
- mailing_address_str_name       object
- city                           object
- state                          object
- zip_code                       object
- etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
X['zip_code'] = X['zip_code'].astype('int64')
```